# Pass multiple attributes in query selector

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I was trying to access below highlighted element using following two query selectors in my puppeteer testing. Neither one is working.

`document.querySelector('div[class="slick-cell l1 r1"][title="08787878787001"]')`

`document.querySelector('div[title="08787878787001"]')`

HTML :

[image]

Still getting no results. I can't place comma between attributes as it consider as "OR" and getting me different element.

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct selector is:

```js
document.querySelector('div.slick-cell.l1.r1')
```

You can read more on selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Selectors don't have text matching like that. If you're trying to match it based on text, use XPath:

```js
$x('//div[@class="slick-cell l1 r1" and @title][text()="08787878787001"]')
```

Comment: Since I have similar attribute values (i.e. `slick-cell.l1.r1`) in above `div` tags, in your solution it get the first one. That's why I need to set the combination.

Comment: @SMPH see my edited answer. let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that is working. So you mean there is no option to use `xpath` in `document.querySelector`?

Comment: @SMPH `document.querySelector` uses selectors not xpath and selectors don't have text matching like that. For xpath, you could use `window.$x()` or directly use `page.$x()` in puppeteer context.